# SQL IN operator value of subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to get a value from an IN subquery with two columns, without needing to do two queries.

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN(SELECT id, flags FROM table2);
```

Now I want to get `flags` directly. Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: IN requires a list of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to achieve one of two things:

1) Select every field of records in table1 (and the associated table 2 flag) where the record's id is also found in the id column of table2. If that is the case, then yes, a join will accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.flags
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Note that `JOIN` is used here (rather than other types of joins such as `LEFT JOIN`) because `JOIN` will return *only* table1 records with a match in table2.id. `LEFT JOIN`, on the other hand, would return *every* table1 record, and table1 ids without a match in table2 would simply have `null` in the flags column of your returned table.

2) Select every field of records in table1 where the record's id is also found in *either* the id column of table2 *or* the flags column of table2. If that is the case, there are a few ways you could get the desired result, but achieving this using a subquery similar to the question

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 UNION DISTINCT SELECT flags FROM table2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do this using `join`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.flags
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```